# Powershell: Format-Table : Illegal key count

Tags: powershell, formatting, invalid-argument

I'm getting the following error and I don't understand why or what it's asking for.

The object I'm trying to display in a table is:

```
function newURLObject()
{
#  param ([String]$Value, [Int]$Count = "1", [String]$IP )
   param ([String]$Value, [Int]$Count = "1" )


  $obj = new-object PSObject
  $obj | add-member -type NoteProperty -Name Value -Value $Value.substring(1)
  $obj | add-member -type NoteProperty -Name Count -Value $Count
 # $obj | add-member -type NoteProperty -Name IP -Value $IP

  return $obj
}
```

The basic flow is the following.

```
#< Declare Objects>
#< Code to create an array of those objects >

$z = @{Expression={$_.Count};Label="Count";width=5}, @{Expression={$_.Value};Label="URL";count=35} 

$y = $listOfRequestedURLs  | sort count -descending | select -first 30 | ft $z 


Format-Table : Illegal key count
At C:\Temp\parse IIS logs.ps1:231 char:8
+ $y | ft <<<<  $z
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Format-Table], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyIllegal,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatTableCommand
```

I know the values are in the array; but it won't display properly.  If I display it without the format-table the value field just shows up as empty.

Answer (score 6):

You have an illegal format key name, remove it (or rename it to width?):

@{Expression={$_.Value};Label="URL";**count=35**}

Comment: Err.. sorry for being dense but I don't understand the difference  with what you've bolded.

Comment: Valid key names are: Expression,FormatString,Label/Name,Width and Alignment. Clearly Count is not one of them.

Comment: Depth is also a valid key name.